# Using API Gateway with IE8

Tags: cors, jsonp, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use API Gateway from my website, but I cannot get IE8 or IE9 to work to consume the webservice. JSONP is how we usually write our ajax services, so they work in all browsers, but that does not seem to be supported. There is CORS support in IE8 and IE9 but is not really implemented to spec, so I am having difficulty getting them to work. This is a real basic post, that works fine using the jquery ajax function, in all but the legacy IE browsers fail with a security error, The request raised an internal browser exception. Error Code:12157, Error Message:ERROR_INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR.

I always get a security error when I try and consume the code.

```
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.open("POST", url);
  xdr.onprogress = function () { };
  xdr.ontimeout = function () { };
  xdr.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Error from XDomainRequest");
  };
  xdr.onload = function() {
    console.log("Success from XDomainRequest - " + xdr.responseText);
  }

  xdr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Comment: Can you expand your question and code? Do you have `CORS` properly setup on the API? Did you try using something like `https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest` ?

Comment: I was never able to get this to work, I guess ie8 just needed to die :)

CORS was enabled and worked fine in other browersers.

I tried other libraries, but that did not solve the problem. The code above is the raw code that should work in IE8